# How do I convert JSON to Array

Tags: c#, arrays, json, string

If I have the JSON string:

```
{"synonyms":["house","abode","appartment","condo","dwelling"]}
```

How do I store this in an array so that in C# it will be this?

```
string[] synonyms = {"house","abode","appartment","condo","dwelling"};
```

I am trying to use the Newtonsoft.Json library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `RootObject` class.

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<string> synonyms { get; set; }
}
```

Create a RootObject by using this:

`RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);`

```
// Acessing synonyms property of obj
List<string> syn = obj.synonyms; // call to Array if you want
```

Comment: @cookies for more complex json data structure you can have your RootObject class created for you by cop&pasting your json in here: http://json2csharp.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this (without using a specific class):

`JToken root = JToken.Parse(yourJsonStringHere);`

`List<string> synonyms = root["synonyms"].ToObject<List<string>>();`

If necessary, you can convert the list to an array using the `ToArray()` method.

Comment: thanks for the alternative solution, I will have to try it sometime, but Matthias' solution does what I need.